# Stopping AVPlayer Loop

Tags: ios, json, swift, database, avplayer

I am developing a music streaming app that streams music from a database. My code dynamically creates buttons for each song in my database, and when these buttons are clicked on they play the mp3 file. However, I cannot figure out how to pause the music and when I click on the buttons more than once, the song plays over itself so two songs are playing at once. I have already tried player.pause() and so on, but nothing is stopping the music from playing/streaming and looping over itself.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

var songArray: [Array<String>] = []  //array to contain song names and filepaths

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //connect to website
    let url = URL(string:"http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team22/SongData.php")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //download JSON data from php page, display data
                    let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String]]
                    print(JSON)

                    //Make buttons with JSON array
                    var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
                    for song in JSON {
                        //add information to array
                        self.songArray.append(song)
                        let SongButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
                        buttonY = buttonY + 50 // 50px spacing

                        SongButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10  //Edge formatting for buttons

                        SongButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray //Color for buttons

                        SongButton.setTitle("\(song[0])", for: UIControlState.normal) //button title

                        SongButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(song[0])" // set title label

                        SongButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(self.songButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)  //button press / response

                        self.view.addSubview(SongButton)  // adds buttons to view
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print(songArray)

}


func songButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton!) { // Streaming function for buttons when pressed
    for song in songArray {
        if  "\(song[0])" == sender.titleLabel?.text { //compare loop element to name of button pressed



            let URL = NSURL(string: song[1])  //plug loop element into audio player
            let player = AVPlayer(url: URL! as URL)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that you are creating a new player each time you click the button and not keeping a reference to it. so you cannot stop/pause or even access the player afterwards.

You should only have one player on the view and only play one item at a time, you can manage a 'playlist' of items to play using [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avqueueplayer) so that you can play items in sequence.

AVQueuePlayer is a subclass of AVPlayer, so you should be able to still call all of the usual functions such as pause/stop.

You initialize it with an array of items (it can just be one to start with) and then add items later.

However you tackle this, you should not have this

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL! as URL)
```

in the function, have a single player or AVQueuePlayer in the view and then you can reference it later. So do `self.player.pause()`